# Magento 1.9 get Protect data

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to find the discount value of a sale, of grouped products

my code is like this, when it is a simple product, the discount value appears, but when it is a product group the value is zero

my code below:

```
$orderItems =  $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
      $items[] = array(
                                'qty' => (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(),
                                'sku' => $item->getSku(),
                                'name' => $item->getName(),
                                'price' => number_format($item->getPrice(), 2),
                                'discount' => number_format($item->getBaseDiscountAmount(), 2),
                                'ERP' => $ehERP
                                );
            }
```

the value $ item-> getBaseDiscountAmount () comes with zero, when product is grouped.

I gave a var_dump ($ item), the discount amount appears in the code below

```
["_data":protected]=>
array(144) {
["entity_id"]=>
string(2) "50"
["state"]=>
string(3) "new"
["status"]=>
string(15) "pending_payment"
["coupon_code"]=>
NULL
["protect_code"]=>
string(6) "5cafe6"
["shipping_description"]=>
string(43) "Formas de Envio: - PAC - Em média 6 dia(s)"
["is_virtual"]=>
string(1) "0"
["store_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["customer_id"]=>
string(2) "36"
["base_discount_amount"]=>
string(7) "-6.4800"
}
```

i need get this value **-6.4800**

Answer (score 0):

Anything under the protected `_data` field can get accessed by using either the getData method: `$item->getData('base_discount_amount')` or the magic method (simply use the camelcase field name) like so: `$item->getBaseDiscountAmount()`

Comment: if i try $item->getData('base_discount_amount') i get this " string(6) "0.0000" " only in group product i get 0, i need get for group product

Comment: Using `getDiscountAmount()` or `getBaseDiscountAmount()` sould definitely do it, like you said it's working for _some_... It does look as though the array you've put in your original post is the data for the order itself, judging by there being customer_id, status, etc. What class is the parent object of `_data` ?

Comment: Inside this ["_data":protected]=>
        array(144) { have ["base_discount_amount"]=>
          string(7) "-6.4800"

Comment: I gave a var_dump ($ item), do you want to look at the whole? he is very big. can i send you in your email?